# TightVNC Resolution on Windows

Tags: tightvnc

I've installed TightVNC on a Windows server and am struggling to get the client connection to display resolutions other than 800x600.

The windows server desktop is configured as 1920x1080 and I have tried issuing the command tvnserver -controlservice -sharerect 1920x1080 with no effect. The "Scale by" setting on the client connection is set to auto.

Does anyone have any tips on getting the higher resolution in the client?

Thanks